# Telethon doesn't send messages when running as service

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I've created a script which sends messages using telethon. The receivers are not always the same: the number of receivers and their IDs are taken from a MySQL table. The multi processing script runs okay in the expected loop when started from the command prompt. But as soon as it's started as a service the messages are not send.

Please see the code below which includes the function to send out the messages. This function is called by another function which loops over the result of a MySQL query.

Can someone shine a light on the question why the function runs fine from the prompt and not as a service?

```
import configparser

# get configuration
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/p2000.cfg')
telegram_api_id = config.get('telegram','api_id')
telegram_api_hash = config.get('telegram','api_hash')
telegram_bot_name = config.get('telegram','bot_name')

client = TelegramClient(telegram_bot_name, telegram_api_id, telegram_api_hash)

def p2k_send_telegram(PeerID,Message):
    async def main():
        await client.send_message(int(PeerID), Message)


    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I assume by "as a service" you mean with systemd, initd, or something similar?

Comment: Yes correct. It's running with systemd.

Comment: To troubleshoot problem, we need to find root of problem. First enable [logging](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/troubleshooting/enable-logging.html) and update question with logs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the answer was easy and right in front of me! The issue could be isolated to the client variable. When running as a service under systemd the session (file) has to be defined with its full path!

Something like this:

`client = TelegramClient('/full/path/to/my.session', telegram_api_id, telegram_api_hash)`